# How can I dynamically name widget variables in gtkmm3?

Tags: c++, string, widget, instantiation, gtkmm3

I am trying to create 10 Gtk::Buttons without going

```
Gtk::Button *button1 = new Gtk::Button;
Gtk::Button *button2 = new Gtk::Button;
Gtk::Button *button3 = new Gtk::Button;
...
Gtk::Button *button10 = new Gtk::Button;

grid.add(*button1); grid.add(*button2); grid.add(*button3); //...
```

---

> A Qt but similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930806/qt-c-naming-of-variables-dynamically)

I have tried the [Qt example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930806/qt-c-naming-of-variables-dynamically), but it has filename and I don't know it is for.

For string array (a list with "button1","button2","button3") loop will generate pointer errors here

```
grid.add(*button1)
         ^_______
```

What I need to happen is to generate dynamic naming for the Buttons' variables and then perform

```
grid.add(*button1);
grid.add(*button2);
grid.add(*button3);
...
grid.add(*button4);
```

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but your question looks more GTK oriented and there’s not enough context for most people to know what you’re asking. Try a minimal, complete, and verifiable example and show what you’ve tried to answer your question. Usually in the process you solve your own problem.

Comment: Ok but I did put Gtkmm tag and let me add and show you what I have done as a code

Comment: I can't quite make out what the problem is or what you're asking. Could you be clearer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I want to generate something that goes between Gtk::Button  `here` = new Gtk::Button, so that I can add it to a Gtk::Notebook page

Comment: Again, you're being too vague. "Generate" how? What is "something"? You say "between" but then name only one thing - "between" means inside of two things. And after clarifying your goal you still need to clearly explain what the problem is! So, what you wanted to happen, and what happened instead, and why you think that is.

Comment: I did explain that I am using `int n = m_notebook.get_n_pages() + 1;
std::string name = "Name" + n;` which is buggy and giving me name as `t`

Comment: Does your `on_switch_account` method even compile, with 2 local variables named `name`?

Comment: Ya it does compile

Comment: I guess what you're trying to do is automatically generate code that will name your variables `account1`, `account2`, etc. Don't do that. Use an array or vector.

Comment: @ptomato thats exactly what I am trying to do let me see if I can try to use an array and tell you what error I face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to make my question clear I ended up picking information from various people and combined it to the following

> main.cpp

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.dynamic.buttons");

  Gtk::Window window;Gtk::Grid grid;
  window.set_default_size(600, 600);
  std::string name = "button";
  std::map<std::string, Gtk::Button*> all_buttons;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    Gtk::Button *button = new Gtk::Button("Button " + std::to_string(i));
    all_buttons[name] = button;
    grid.add(*button);
  }
  window.add(grid);
  window.show_all_children();

  return app->run(window);
}
```

---

Thanks to [ptomato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172999/ptomato) & [Peter87](http://www.cplusplus.com/user/Peter87/)